# How do I make a switch button?

Tags: c#

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button13.ForeColor = Color.Red;
   debugMode = true;
}
```

I want following set once I click the button:

```
button13.ForeColor = Color.Red;
debugMode = true;
```

And next time I will click the button so the button will be back to `Color.Black` and `debugMode` will be `false`.

And if its on the other switch, if the button `Color.Black` and `debugMode` is `false` and I click the button the values change `Color.Red` and `debugMode` is `true`.

I already have a bool variable for using

`debugButtonSwitch`

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use `debugMode` like this:

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button13.ForeColor = (debugMode) ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
   debugMode = !debugMode;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button13.ForeColor = (debugMode) ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
   debugMode = !debugMode;
}
```

And if you want to change the button status from another event you can put this code inside the separate method and call it anywhere that you need